# Resolution when enter fullScreen on android Browser

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, browser, unity-webgl

When I was running my **unityGL** program , I used `Screen.fullScreen = true;` to enter the full screen mode.

It works, I enter fullscreen and I get the resolution same as on my desktop.

But when I run it in a Android browser, something is not right.

So I use **UGUI** to get the `Screen.width` and `Screen.height`
then I find out when I open the page, text shows the resolution like I set `960X600`.

But if I enter fullScreen the resolution will change to `360X640`.

Where did the `360X640` come from, and how do I change the resolution number?

*edit
if i rotate the phone and enter fullScreen , the resolution well change to `640X360`

Comment: This could be a problem with your `Canvas` component (I assume you have one in your game). Make sure its `UI Scale Mode` is set to: Scale with screen size. Also in your `PlayerSettings` what is the WebGL Template you are using, and what is the Default Canvas resolution?

Comment: my `UI Scale Mode` set is `PlayerSettings` 
Default Canvas resolution is 960X640

Comment: Try adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no
  initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />` to your html `<head>` tag in your template.

Comment: it not work,resolution still low